# Evaluate this integral : $\int \frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int \frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}dx$$
I had this question for today's test and still can't find out how to do it. Any hint is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint : $$\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}=\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}}=\frac{\sinh(x)}{\cosh(x)}=\frac{u'}{u}$$ with $u=\cosh(x)$.

Comment: Note that you don't need to go all the way to $\sinh$ and $\cosh$ to show that $\frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{e^x + e^{-x}}$ is of the form $\frac{u'}u$. Still, this is probably the easiest way to go.

Comment: They didn't yet thought me hyperbolic cosines and sines. There should be another way ?

Comment: Why do $\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}=\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}}$?

Comment: @H G Sur : As Arthur said, you can avoid the hyperbolic step and notice that you have a $u'/u$ form in the previous step.

Comment: @gbox = $\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}} = \frac{e^x(e^{x}-e^{-x})}{e^{x}(e^{x}+e^{-x})}= \frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}$

Comment: @C.Dubussy Great, now I understand :)

Answer (score 3):

$$I=\int \frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}dx$$
$$I=\int \frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}}dx$$
$$e^{x}+e^{-x}=t$$
$$\implies \{e^{x}-e^{-x}\}dx=dt$$
$$I=\int\frac{dt}{t}$$

Answer (score 1):

Set $e^x=y\implies x=\ln y,dx=\dfrac{dy}y$

$$\int\dfrac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}dx=\dfrac{y^2-1}{(y^2+1)y}\ dy$$

Use [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html)
$$\dfrac{y^2-1}{(y^2+1)y}=\dfrac{Ay+B}{y^2+1}+\dfrac Cy$$

$$\implies y^2-1=(Ay+B)y+C(y^2+1)=y^2(A+C)+By+C$$

$$\implies C=-1,A+C=1, B=0$$

Answer (score 1):

### Hint

$$\frac{e^{2x}-e^{2x}+e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}=\frac{2e^{2x}-e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}=-1+\frac{2e^{2x}}{e^{2x}+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers are a bit more elegant than mine, but my thinking was, quick and dirty,

$$\int\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}dx = \int\frac{e^{2x}}{e^{2x}+1}dx - \int\frac{1} {e^{2x}+1}dx = \int\frac{2e^{2x}}{2(e^{2x}+1)}dx + \int\frac{-2e^{-2x}}{2(1+e^{-2x})}dx = \frac{1}{2}(\ln(e^{2x}+1) + \ln(e^{-2x}+1)) + C = \frac{1}{2}\ln(2+e^{2x}+e^{-2x})+C$$